# how can go to previous activity with current state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

have two Activity , in my Activity1 have button go to Activity2

```
 Intent mIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainA2ctivity.class);
 startActivity(mIntent);
```

in my Activity2 have player with play resume button and seek bar which when play song that become like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqt4B.jpg)

and this is my press back code in Activity2:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    Intent mIntent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(mIntent);

}
```

in Activity1 have another button which i want when click that go to activity 2 with current play pause button and seekbar and this is my code :

```
 Intent mIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
 startActivity(mIntent);
```

but problem is when go in acitvity2 song is playing but seekbar and play pause button still like first time :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5MMb.jpg)

Comment: You should save the state in a sharedpreference or something.

Comment: @Karun Shrestha dont need save that for all time . just when use in app

Comment: If so then use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send state data from **MainActivity** to **Main2Activity** back and forth

**MainActivity** code

```
final int REQUEST_PLAYPROG = 22; // custom int code

Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("playState", isPlaying);
mIntent.putExtra("progress", seekbarProgress);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, REQUEST_PLAYPROG);
```

In **Main2Activity** you will retrive data like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null) {
    boolean isPlaying = bundle.getBoolean("playState");
    int seekbarProgress = bundle.getInt("progress");
}
```

And transfer from A to B is done, now you have to send back data from B to A onBackPressed

This is **Main2Activity** code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    mIntent.putExtra("playState", isPlaying);
    mIntent.putExtra("progress", seekbarProgress);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
    finish();
}
```

And finally retrive data in **MainActivity** through onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_PLAYPROG && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        boolean isPlaying = data.getExtras().getBoolean("playState"), 
        int seekbarProgress = data.getExtras().getInt("progress"), 
    }
}
```

Comment: still same problem. are you sure about where codes must be in which activity ?

Comment: Yes I've tested before submit

Comment: which one of codes must put in button when want to Main2Activity when player and seekbar is active ?

Comment: The first block, put it in the Button onClickListener on the first Activity "MainActivity"; the second block on the second activity "Main2Activity" in onCreate; the third block in second activity onBackPressed; the last block in first Activity onActivityResult

Comment: do your exact way but not work still when go back to Main2Activity seekbar and play button is freez

Comment: You can send me the entire source code of the two activities in private

Comment: do you have telegram ?

Comment: Yes i have Telegram, I will add you ;)

Comment: @Erifun73  its my teleg please add me

Comment: Just send me your Contact Number at my email address tiziano@mabiloft.com

Comment: check your telegram

Answer (score 0):

You can use onSaveInstanceState to save the activity state, and onRestoreInstanceState to restore the state, Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putInt("play", true);
    savedInstanceState.putString("playtime", "1:20");
    // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    play = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("play");
    playtime = savedInstanceState.getString("playtime");
}
```

Remember this won't work if the activity is killed.

Comment: i dont need boolean and string variables ... i want when reaload activity seekbar loaded where must be and my button is playing ...

Comment: for that you should save where the seek bar is and if the music should be played or not

Comment: you said it work when we dont finish activity lookat on my back press it not finish yes ?

Comment: i said the code i've mentioned above will not work if the activity is finished